# How to insert a attribute with a dynamic value in many object or add an element dynamically in many array?

Tags: jmespath

I want to add an attribute in many object(situated in an array) and this value will be get dynamically. I use the JSON below, and I already made a query to extract what I want. We will start with th result of this query.

First my entire JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "Nature":"lol",
      "EV":"lol",
      "Moves":[  
         {  
"Move":"OHKOmove",
            "Max":100,
            "Min":15
         },
         {  
"Move":"cacaz",
            "Max":35,
            "Min":20
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Nature":"loi",
      "EV":"lal",
      "Moves":[  
         {  
"Move":"caca1",
            "Max":100,
            "Min":3
         },
{  
"Move":"caca2",
            "Max":100,
            "Min":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Nature":"loi2",
      "EV":"lal",
      "Moves":[  
         {  
"Move":"caca1",
            "Max":100,
            "Min":3
         },
{  
"Move":"caca2",
            "Max":100,
            "Min":3
         },
{  
"Move":"caca3",
            "Max":100,
            "Min":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Nature":"loi3",
      "EV":"lil",
      "Moves":[  
         {  
"Move":"caca1",
            "Max":100,
            "Min":3
         },
{  
"Move":"caca2",
            "Max":100,
            "Min":3
         },
{  
"Move":"caca3",
            "Max":100,
            "Min":3
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Then my query: `` [?(length(Moves[?Max == `100`]) > `1`)].{Nature: Nature, EV: EV, Moves: Moves[?Max == `100`].Move, MovesCount: length(Moves[?Max == `100`].Move)} | [@,{MaxMouvCount: max_by(@, &MovesCount).MovesCount}][] ``

And the result of my query give this:

#### JSON Format Example 1

```
[
 {
   "Nature": "loi",
   "EV": "lal",
   "Moves": [
     "caca1",
     "caca2"
   ],
   "MovesCount": 2
 },
 {
   "Nature": "loi2",
   "EV": "lal",
   "Moves": [
     "caca1",
     "caca2",
     "caca3"
   ],
   "MovesCount": 3
 },
 {
   "Nature": "loi3",
   "EV": "lil",
   "Moves": [
     "caca1",
     "caca2",
     "caca3"
   ],
   "MovesCount": 3
 },
 {
   "MaxMouvCount": 3
 }
]
```

The idea is to put the attribute `"MaxMouvCount": 3` on each objects in the array and then delete it from the array to give a result like this:

#### JSON Format Example 2

```
[
  {
    "Nature": "loi",
    "EV": "lal",
    "Moves": [
      "caca1",
      "caca2"
    ],
    "MovesCount": 2,
    "MaxMouvCount": 3
  },
  {
    "Nature": "loi2",
    "EV": "lal",
    "Moves": [
      "caca1",
      "caca2",
      "caca3"
    ],
    "MovesCount": 3,
    "MaxMouvCount": 3
  },
  {
    "Nature": "loi3",
    "EV": "lil",
    "Moves": [
      "caca1",
      "caca2",
      "caca3"
    ],
    "MovesCount": 3,
    "MaxMouvCount": 3
  }
]
```

In the title I talk about array, in fact with `.*` after my query I can transform the object in array and maybe put more easier the value in each array(matching with objects) and retransform array into object with object constructor. But I don't know how to do it. Can you help me please or tell me at least if it's possible.

PS: I use only JMESPath so I don't want an answer with any other language which contains JMESPath code(like javascript(in my case) or python or something else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Usually it is easy to painlessly transform JSON with JMESPath

  - One pain-free key is to utilize JSON structures that are specifically normalized for optimal use with JMESPath
  - One pain-free key is knowing when to use dictionary (aka objects // associative-arrays // mappings) name-value pairs in your JSON to make all parts of the JSON capable of unambiguous reference
- Unfortunately, the goal in this specific question is **not doable** with standard JMESPath, because JMESPath lacks a token to refer to the JSON data root in the `current-node` context

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- JMESPath query language
- `python 3.x` using `JMESPath 0.9.4` [but any JMESPath engine will do]

#### Problem

- **Scenario:**

  - DeveloperSObosskay972 wishes to transform JSON data from one representation to another
  - DeveloperSObosskay972 wants to rely solely on JMESPath expressions to complete the transformation
  - DeveloperSObosskay972 wants to refer to one part of the JSON structure in another part, to allow for dynamic cross-referencing of the datastructure

#### Attempt 01 (not what we really want)

- the "almost" solution that is not quite what we want
- this code ...

```py
import jmespath
vdata001aa = """<<json.load(JSON Format Example 1)>>"""
vresult = jmespath.compile('@|[*].{"Nature":@.Nature,"EV":@.EV,"Moves":@.Moves,"MovesCount":@.MovesCount,"MaxMouvCount":`3`}').search(vdata001aa)
pprint.pprint(vresult)
```

- produces this result ...

```py
[{'EV': 'lal',
  'MaxMouvCount': 3,
  'Moves': ['caca1', 'caca2'],
  'MovesCount': 2,
  'Nature': 'loi'},
 {'EV': 'lal',
  'MaxMouvCount': 3,
  'Moves': ['caca1', 'caca2', 'caca3'],
  'MovesCount': 3,
  'Nature': 'loi2'},
 {'EV': 'lil',
  'MaxMouvCount': 3,
  'Moves': ['caca1', 'caca2', 'caca3'],
  'MovesCount': 3,
  'Nature': 'loi3'},
 {'EV': None,
  'MaxMouvCount': 3,
  'Moves': None,
  'MovesCount': None,
  'Nature': None}]
```

- This is not what we want, because:

  - we had to hardwire the value `3` for `MaxMouvCount` which is technically "cheating"

    - it's cheating because we want a *dynamic* value, not a *hard-wired* value
  - this produces a superfluous element where every value except MaxMouvCount is `null` (python happens to call this `None`)
  - we only wanted three elements, not four

#### Attempt 02 (not what we really want)

- The reason why Attempt 01 does not work well is because the original JSON stucture is not well-normalized for JMESPath
- In order to address this, we add dictionary name-value pairs to the original data
- With this approach, we make *every element* of the JSON data a value attached to a dictionary key (aka javascript object name-value pairs)

  - Here we use the term `dictionary` which is known in other contexts as `object` or `hash` or `associative array` or `mapping`
  - We don't care about the terminology, so much as the ability to refer to all parts of the top-level JSON as name-value pairs

Attempt 02 // Part 1 (reformat JSON Format Example 1)

- reformat your original JSON `JSON Format Example 1` so it looks like this instead
- this reformatted JSON will make all parts of your data unambiguously addressible

```js
{
"jsontop": {
    "settings_info": {
      "MaxMouvCount": 3
    },
    "nature_table": [
     {
       "Nature": "loi",
       "EV": "lal",
       "Moves": [
         "caca1",
         "caca2"
       ],
       "MovesCount": 2
     },
     {
       "Nature": "loi2",
       "EV": "lal",
       "Moves": [
         "caca1",
         "caca2",
         "caca3"
       ],
       "MovesCount": 3
     },
     {
       "Nature": "loi3",
       "EV": "lil",
       "Moves": [
         "caca1",
         "caca2",
         "caca3"
       ],
       "MovesCount": 3
     }
    ]
}
```

Attempt 02 // Part 2 (run the pain-free JMESPath query to get what you want)

- this code ...

```py
import jmespath
vdata001aa  = """<<json.load(**RE-NORMALIZED** JSON Format Example 1)>>"""
vresult     = jmespath.compile('@|jsontop.nature_table[*].{"Nature":@.Nature,"EV":@.EV,"Moves":@.Moves,"MovesCount":@.MovesCount,"MaxMouvCount":jsontop.settings_info.MaxMouvCount}').search(vdata001aa)
pprint.pprint(vresult)
pass
```

- produces this result ...

```
[{'EV': 'lal',
  'MaxMouvCount': None,
  'Moves': ['caca1', 'caca2'],
  'MovesCount': 2,
  'Nature': 'loi'},
 {'EV': 'lal',
  'MaxMouvCount': None,
  'Moves': ['caca1', 'caca2', 'caca3'],
  'MovesCount': 3,
  'Nature': 'loi2'},
 {'EV': 'lil',
  'MaxMouvCount': None,
  'Moves': ['caca1', 'caca2', 'caca3'],
  'MovesCount': 3,
  'Nature': 'loi3'}]
```

- this is not what we want, because we get `None` (aka `null`) where we expected `3`

### Explanation

- Attempt 02 **would** have worked, if JMESPath supported a token to refer to the JSON root object
- An alternate query which would work is (if for example, the dollar-sign character worked as a reference to the JSON data root)

```py
import jmespath
vdata001aa  = """<<json.load(**RE-NORMALIZED** JSON Format Example 1)>>"""
vresult     = jmespath.compile('@|jsontop.nature_table[*].{"Nature":@.Nature,"EV":@.EV,"Moves":@.Moves,"MovesCount":@.MovesCount,"MaxMouvCount":$.jsontop.settings_info.MaxMouvCount}').search(vdata001aa)
pprint.pprint(vresult)
pass
```

- There is actually a project on GitHub that addresses this limitation of JMESPath

  - https://github.com/grofers/go-codon/wiki/Jmespath-extensions#3-added--to-refer-to-root-node

### Conclusion

- Attempt 01 and Attempt 02 show that the current (stable) version of JMESPath does not quite have the ability to meet the requirement
- You will have to break out of JMESPath to get the desired dynamic value from your JSON and populate the reformatted data
- Alternatively, you will have to add an extension to JMESPath itself, which is arguably less desirable than using the functionality of the hosting language